# How to search specific unicode tokens in the list in python

Tags: string, python-2.7, list, unicode

I want to search a specific string from the file for which the code is as follows

```
f1= codecs.open('brokenhindi.txt', encoding='utf-8')
for tokens in f1:
    if u"राज्य" in tokens:
        print 'done_3'
```

but it did not search the string(राज्य), if I replace राज्य with an english token then it searches it. I cannot  find the error in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code just works fine.
It seems though that your script or your text file is ascii encoded rather than utf-8.
Try to save it as utf-8 encoded